Cuando actualizo o elimino algún registro de una tabla que visualizo en mi página, se actualiza pero ya no me muestra los registros restantes
tengo mi página en php que administra solicitudes que vienen de otras páginas relacionadas. Todas las solicitudes son registros que se insertan en mi base de datos y luego modifico y/o elimino desde esta página de administración. El problema es que una vez que actualizo o elimino algún registro, el contenido se actualiza pero ya no me muestra los registros restantes; es más hasta debo cerrar la página y volver a ingresarla en la barra de búsqueda del navegador para poder ver el contenido nuevamente. Mi contenido se muestra según la opción que elija en un select que me muestra dos opciones, cada opción es una tabla diferente y el contenido se muestra en un  vacío hasta que se elije la opción y me muestra una tabla con los datos. Además vi que también esta eliminando mi footer luego de modificación/eliminación de datos. ¿Cuál podría ser el problema? Desde ya muchas gracias!
'''<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location: Tesis.php");
    exit;
}

$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="shorcut icon" href="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/656/PNG/512/settings_online_web_pc_mac_monitor_icon-icons.com_59975.png">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Administrador</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    
/* Estilos de botones */
.btn{
      font-size: large;
      margin-inline-start: 20px;
    }
.btn:hover{
      border-radius: 5px;
      filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #000);
    }

  .form-label{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
  }

  table {  
    width: 100%;  
    border-collapse: collapse;
}  

th, td {  
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
    padding: 10px;  
    text-align: left; 
}  

th {  
    border-radius: 15px; 
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
}  

tr:hover {  
    background-color: #f1f1f1; 
}

  select {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /*Footer*/
  .Contenedorfooter{
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .footer a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
    }

    .footer a:hover{
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
      color:#000;
      text-decoration: underline;
     }

     #Facebook:hover{
      border-radius: 0px;
      transform: scale(1.2);
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #000);
     }
     #Whatsapp:hover{
      transform: scale(1.2);
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      border-radius: 5px;
      filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #000);
     }
     #Regresar:hover{
      transform: scale(1.2);
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      border-radius: 0px;
      filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #000);
     }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container py-2">
        <!--Menú de Navegación-->
        <div class="card bg-light" id=header-border2>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Tesis.php">
                        <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/656/PNG/512/settings_online_web_pc_mac_monitor_icon-icons.com_59975.png" alt="" height="100px">
                    </a>
                    <h1>PCRepair</h1>
                    <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
                        <h2 class="mt-2 text-primary">Administración de Solicitudes</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!--Administrador consultas-->
        <hr>
        <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
            <select class="InforMostrada" id="InforMostrada">
                <option>Elija una opción de contenido</option>
                <option value="opcion1">Solicitudes de Software</option>
                <option value="opcion2">Solicitudes de Desinfección</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <div id="contenido">
            </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Función para cargar datos en el modal setup
    function cargarDatosModal(id, nombre, email, so, soft) {
        document.getElementById('idSetup').value = id;
        document.getElementById('nombreS').value = nombre;
        document.getElementById('emailS').value = email;
        document.getElementById('soDeseado').value = so;
        document.getElementById('softSolicitados').value = soft;
    }

    // Función para cargar datos en el modal health
    function cargarDatosModalHealth(id, nombre, email, descripcion) {
        document.getElementById('idHealth').value = id;
        document.getElementById('nombreH').value = nombre;
        document.getElementById('emailH').value = email;
        document.getElementById('descripcionH').value = descripcion;
    }

    function actualizarContenido() {
        const selectElement = document.getElementById('InforMostrada');
        const contenidoDiv = document.getElementById('contenido');
        const valorSeleccionado = selectElement.value;
        
        
        if (valorSeleccionado == 'opcion1') {
            contenidoDiv.innerHTML = `<?php
                $conex = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tesis');
                $consulta = "select * from setup";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);

                if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['action'])) {  
                    if ($_POST['action'] == 'AceptarCambios') {
                        $idSetup = $_POST['idSetup'];  
                        $nombreS = $_POST['nombreS'];  
                        $emailS = $_POST['emailS'];  
                        $soDeseado = $_POST['soDeseado'];
                        $softSolicitados = $_POST['softSolicitados'];  

                        $actualizar = "UPDATE setup SET nombreS = '$nombreS', emailS = '$emailS', soDeseado= '$soDeseado', softSolicitados = '$softSolicitados' WHERE idSetup = '$idSetup'";    
                        mysqli_query($conex, $actualizar);  
                        
                        
                        
                    } elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {  
                        $idSetup = $_POST['idSetup'];  
                        $eliminar = "DELETE FROM setup WHERE idSetup = '$idSetup'";  
                        mysqli_query($conex, $eliminar);
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                } 
                
                echo "<table id='table'>";
                echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Email</th><th>Software Operativo</th><th>Software Deseado</th><th>Edición</th><th>Eliminación</th></tr>";

                while ($x = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["idSetup"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["nombreS"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["emailS"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["soDeseado"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["softSolicitados"] . "</td>";
                    
                    echo "<td>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' 
                            data-bs-target='#modalActualiza' 
                            onclick='cargarDatosModal(\"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["idSetup"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["nombreS"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["emailS"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["soDeseado"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["softSolicitados"]) . "\")'>
                            Modificar
                        </button>
                    </td>";

                    echo "<td>
                        <form method='POST' action='' style='display:inline;'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='idSetup' value='" . $x["idSetup"] . "'>  
                            <input type='hidden' name='action' value='delete'>  
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' value='Eliminar' onclick='return confirm(\"¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar este registro?\");'>  
                        </form>
                    </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($conex);
            ?>`;

        } else if (valorSeleccionado == 'opcion2') {
            contenidoDiv.innerHTML = `<?php
                $conex = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tesis');
                $consulta = "select * from health";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);
                
                if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['action'])) {  
                    if ($_POST['action'] == 'cambia') {
                        $idHealth = $_POST['idHealth'];  
                        $nombreH = $_POST['nombreH'];  
                        $emailH = $_POST['emailH'];  
                        $descripcionH = $_POST['descripcionH'];
                        
                        $actualizar = "UPDATE health SET nombreH = '$nombreH', emailH = '$emailH', descripcionH = '$descripcionH' WHERE idHealth = '$idHealth'";    
                        mysqli_query($conex, $actualizar);

                        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                        exit;    
                    } elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'kill') {  
                        $idHealth = $_POST['idHealth'];  
                        $eliminar = "DELETE FROM health WHERE idHealth = '$idHealth'";
                        mysqli_query($conex, $eliminar);
               
                        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                        exit;  
                        
                    }  
                } 
                
                echo "<table id='table'>";
                echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Email</th><th>Descripción</th><th>Edición</th><th>Eliminación</th></tr>";
                while ($x = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["idHealth"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["nombreH"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["emailH"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $x["descripcionH"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' 
                            data-bs-target='#modalActualizaHealth' 
                            onclick='cargarDatosModalHealth(\"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["idHealth"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["nombreH"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["emailH"]) . "\", \"" . 
                            htmlspecialchars($x["descripcionH"]) . "\")'>
                            Modificar
                        </button>
                    </td>";
                    echo "<td>
                        <form method='POST' action='' style='display:inline;'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='idHealth' value='" . $x["idHealth"] . "'>  
                            <input type='hidden' name='action' value='kill'>  
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' value='Eliminar' onclick='return confirm(\"¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar este registro?\");'>  
                        </form>
                    </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($conex);
            ?>`;
        }
    }
    
    // SeConfigurar el event listener para el select
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('InforMostrada');
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
        actualizarContenido();
    }); 


    </script>

    <!-- Modal de Actualización Setup -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalActualiza" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-light">
                <h3 class="modal-title text-center">Actualización de Datos</h3>
                <button class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="AceptarCambios">
            
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idSetup" name="idSetup" readonly>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreS" name="nombreS" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailS" name="emailS" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Sistema Operativo Deseado:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="soDeseado" name="soDeseado" required>
                            <option value="">Seleccione SO deseado</option>
                            <option value="Microsoft Windows 10 Pro">Microsoft Windows 10 Pro</option>
                            <option value="Microsoft Windows 11 Pro">Microsoft Windows 11 Pro</option>
                            <option value="GNU/Linux">GNU/Linux</option>
                            <option value="MacOs">MacOs</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Software Solicitado:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="softSolicitados" name="softSolicitados" rows="2" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal de Actualización Health -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalActualizaHealth" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-light">
                <h3 class="modal-title text-center">Actualización de Datos de Desinfección</h3>
                <button class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cambia">
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idHealth" name="idHealth" readonly>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreH" name="nombreH" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailH" name="emailH" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-label">Descripción:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcionH" name="descripcionH" rows="2" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
<hr>
    <!-- Footer Enlaces -->
     <div class="Contenedorfooter">
        <!--DIVISOR-->           

    <div class="card bg-light">
      <div class="footer d-flex justify-content-center bg-light mt-2" id="footer">
        <a href="#inicial" class="ms-0 me-4"><img src="img/Regresar.png" style="width: 25px;height: 25px;" id="Regresar" onclick="scrollToSection(inicial)"></a>
        <a href="" class="me-2 " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#poli">Políticas de privacidad</a>
        <a href="" class="me-2 " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#termi">Términos y Condiciones</a>
        <p class="ms-4">Contáctenos</p>
        <a href="https://wa.me/3564638423" target="_blank" class="ms-2 me-2"><img src="img/Whatsapp.png" style="width: 25px;height: 25px;" id="Whatsapp" alt=""></a>
        <p>Siganos en nuestra red social</p>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/people/Pcs-Repair/61559353245060/" target="_blank" class="ms-2"><img src="img/Facebook.png" style="width: 30px;height: 30px;" id="Facebook" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>     
'''

    
    


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

le encontré una solución momentánea muy básica. Lo que hice fue volver a tipar la variable que me muestra los resultados completos de mi consulta "$resultado=mysqli_query(conex,consulta);" debajo de cada consulta ya sea update o delete.
